# Any solution for this blue screen loop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, dism

folks! I am not an experienced windows os user and hope you can help with this.

Few days ago I downloaded some windows updates. Posterior to restart it was showing a blue screen with some troubleshooting options/tools. Firstly I tried `Startup Repair` but after restart it failed ("blue screen of death") and troubleshooting options were shown again. Then I used `System Restore` and one recorded point on my PC has a date just before the updates so I selected that one and continued. It ended successfully and restarted the system and one more time: blue screen loop. Next I attempted an older recorded point in system restore tool but this time it prompted a warning "Confirm which drive you want to restore. You must restore the drive that contains windows" so I looking for a way I could select C: in system restore I ran `net start vss`, `rstui.exe /offline:C:\windows=active` this last command immediately opened system restore program yet it finished this time with error `0x80070002` (unspecified error occurred)... Summarizing the second half of the story I also tried:

- `BOOTREC /FIXMBR` and `BOOTREC /FIXBOOT` to fix boot however the second command raised an "Access Denied" error
- `sfc /scannow` having as a result "resource protection could not perform the requested operation"
- `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` and `DISM /Image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image ...` with no success.
- Any `Safe Mode` startup option fails/loops
- Troubleshooting options to `uninstall updates` crash and exit
- `chkdsk /f /r` with no errors but after restart it loops to blue screen
  I cannot lose programs and personal files. I have windows 10

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: 0x80070002 means windows error number 2 = File not found. Type in Setting's search box `problem reports` and post details. Try booting into safe mode in startup options.

Comment: Sorry, where is settings search box located? About safe mode it also fails and loops to blue screen

Comment: Where are you typing these commands?

Comment: All commands should be entered at an Administrator command prompt. Assuming you can't get into your os, you should be doing these from the recovery environment. If you can't spawn a shell or launch the recovery environment from the windows 10 metro boot menu, you will need to write a windows 10 install disk to a USB and boot from it. Before it attempts to install, it will give an option to boot to recovery environment

Comment: I thought I didn't have administrator rights but I did a check while running all commands above and I was. Ok, I gotta try